# 2 divs next to each other in qtip1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, qtip

I want to show a popup using `qTip1` with 2 divs, the first one contains a picture and has to be on the left, the second one has some text in a table and has to be on the right. The problem is when I create the inner HTML for `qTip`, the table with the text is always under the picture and not on the right. I've tried some solutions here on stackoverflow but I think I'm missing something.

This is what the generated inner HTML for `qTip` looks like:

```html
<div id="infoBoxParent" style="margin: 20px 20px 0 0; border: 1px solid #333; overflow: auto">
    <div id="infoBoxPicture" style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;"><img
            src="foo.png"
            alt="" width="111" height="170" class="photo left" style="float: left;"/></div>
    <div id="infoBoxFacts" style="float: right; border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style='padding:5px;text-align:left;'>Some Text:</td>
                <td style='padding:5px;text-align:right;'>Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional
                    and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A
                    sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every
                    question about programming.

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to remove all the inline css and put the following code in the header.
This should work.

```
<style>
   #infoBoxParent {
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
    #infoBoxParent div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    }
    #infoBoxPicture{
    border-color: green;
    width: 30%;
    }
    #infoBoxFacts{
    border-color: red;
    width: 68%; /* 2% margin for the lines */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: In fact, the problem comes from the table which takes 100% width. You just need to specify a width for your infoBoxPicture & infoBoxFacts divs (ex: 30% - 70%) and you'll be OK.

Comment: Please add your last comment to your answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question this should work. It is from a css framework I built(Responder). I removed a lot of code so it highlights the solution to your question. The `.reponsive-image` class is not necessary but I added it because you are using images in your project.

If you want to change the width of your columns you can add classes to your style sheet in the folowing fashion:

```
   .column25{

      max-width:25%;
      width:25%:

   }
```

There is a link below for Responder that has a lot of these classes typed out already if you need to copy them.

Link to Solution Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/OMEoMq

Link to Responder CSS framework: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/XmzQba

CSS:

```
/*makes an image responsive*/

.responsive-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* responsive container for the column classes*/

.row {
  /*set the max width of the .row class to 
  *to 100% so the columns within it do not exceed
  *a sum of 100% combined 
  */

  max-width: 100%;
  /*keeps the .row divs next each other when the screen
    resizes*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row div {
  /* adjust the aspect of the font
  * so it displays well and within the div elements 
  * when the screen is resized
  * 
  */
  font-size-adjust: 0.45;
  line-height: 1.5;
  /*provide some spacing in between the lines*/
  float: left;
  /*removes spacing between in line elements*/
  clear: none;
  /*removes spacing between in line elements*/
  display: inline-block;
  /*make the div elements align horizonatally*/
  /*styling below prevents padding and borders from breaking
  the max-width setting of the columns*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Opera/IE 8+ */
  /*allow long words to wrap to another line*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
}


/*begin section for styling the column widths*/

.column50 {
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="infoBoxParent" style="border: 1px solid #333; overflow: auto">
  <div class="column50" id="infoBoxPicture" style="border: 1px solid green;"><img src="foo.png" alt="foo image" width="111" height="170" class="photo left" style="" /></div>
  <div class="column50" id="infoBoxFacts" style="border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style='padding:5px;text-align:left;'>Some Text:</td>
        <td style='padding:5px;text-align:right;'>Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers
          to every question about programming.

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```